# Upgrading Django version

Tags: cookiecutter-django

I am trying to update the django version in requirements/base.txt from 3.0.11 to 3.1

requirements/base.txt

```
# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
django==3.1  # pyup: < 3.1  # https://www.djangoproject.com/
```

Does upgrading Django version in the project would create  a problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the official documentation it doesn't seem to have any compatibility issue.
However, you have to see all the dependencies that your project uses.

For exemple, if a requirement `poll` uses django and has defined its requirements.txt file as `django<3.0`, so you will have an error.

In general, the best way is to create a new virtual environment and test if there are any dependency issues.

```sh
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 manage.py test
python3 manage.py runserver
```